# Intval Returning 0 on "'[number]'"

Tags: php

I have an array being sent through headers of my PHP page, and am taking the ID's as keys to the values.

When I do:

```
echo ($id);
```

I get:

```
"'1234'"
```

I'm trying to send this $id into my mysqli prepared statement, which takes the $id as an integer. When I try and convert this value either with:

```
(int) $id;
```

or

```
intval($id);
```

I get 0 as my integer. How can I get the integer of this string without using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why the single quotes are there, but you can trim them off. I assume they're the reason you're getting zero when you try to convert it to int.

```
trim($id, "'");
```

Also I'm not sure if the double quotes are actually part of the echo output or if you just quoted it in the question, but you can trim off both if they're both there.

```
trim($id, "'\"");
```

If I were you I would go back a step, figure out why the quotes are part of the ID and keep that from happening in the first place (if possible).

Comment: Thank you!!! That's a handy and simple solution; I'll mark it correct once I'm able to!

Answer (score 0):

U can get with regex [0-9]+ pattern

```
$str="'1234'";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was looking to avoid regex